# DBD:SQLite disconnect

Tags: perl, sqlite, cpan, dbi

I wrote the below code:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:SQLite:mysqlite.db', "", "") || die "Cannot connect: $DBI::errstr";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select value1, value2 from valus_table where value2 = 4");

$sth->execute();

while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {
    print $row[0], $row[1], "\n";
}

$sth->finish;

$dbh->disconnect();
```

and get this warning:

```
closing dbh with active statement handles at mysqlib.pl line 23
```

Could someone explain the meaning of this warning message?

Answer (score 4):

the code you posted is correct (except of a syntax error on line 1)

Also your error is on line "23" and your posted code doesn't have 23 lines.

I think the error is somewhere else in your code.

Edit:
What version do you use of the SQLite module? I goggled a bit and found that: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=665714

> The problem is that DBD::SQlite->disconnect() method execute
>   sqlite3_close() function. This function return SQLITE_BUSY in case if
>   there are any active statement. From API: "Applications should
>   finalize all prepared statements and close all BLOBs associated with
>   the sqlite3 object prior to attempting to close the sqlite3 object."
>   Currently DBD::SQLite can finalize statements only via DESTROY method.
>   In simplest case you can always use "undef $sth" or wait untill it
>   goes out of scope which will finalize statement. But if you prepared
>   statement via cache (prepare_cached) it will not work for you, because
>   statement is till inside DBI cache. In this case we can call DESTROY
>   on our cached statement only via DESTROY for database handler. And we
>   can achieve it by "undef $dbh". "undef $dbh" - will close all cached
>   statements and close database without any errors. Conclusion: avoid
>   using $dbh->disconnect() for DBD::SQLite, instead use "undef $dbh".

Regards,

jfried